# Laravel 3 How to use different session settings depending on URL

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-3

My website developed with `laravel-3` has two differentiated sections:

- **public**. Which url is `/`
- **admin**. Which url is `/admin`

In public section users can login to access their accounts, while in admin only those users with required permissions are allowed to login.

Right now I'm not able to differentiate the session being used in one section from another, as both use the same `session` configuration parameters, and therefore anyone logged in public section is allowed to enter in admin area.

I've been thinking on define an environment for the `admin` section and define different values for `cookie` and `path`:

```
$environments = array(
// Local
   'admin' => array('http://localhost*/admin'),  // To handle anything inside section "admin"
   'local' => array('http://localhost*'),        // To handle everything else
);
```

But because `Request::detect_env()` only checks these rules with the url root, the `admin` environment is never seen `(laravel/core.php:183)`.

```
$root = Request::foundation()->getRootUrl();
$environment = Request::detect_env($environments, $root);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to not use environment for this problem, but rather a filter with wildcard in order to delegate the verification :

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'login_admin_filter');
```

But if you really want to use environment, I understand the documentation like that :

In your start file you should use a closure :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    // This condition need to fail if the user isn't an administrator
    if($_SESSION['anything'] == 'admin' OR $every_thing_else){
        return 'admin';        
    } else {
        return 'production';
});
```

Comment: I guess you call `Auth::attempt()` inside that `login_admin_filter`? That ends using the session parameters I'm trying to customize.

Comment: I verify : `Auth::check()` inside the filter. If it fails I redirect on a login form which try to connect the user with attempt(). The difficulty will be to differentiate 2 kind of login (1 admi and 1 normal user), but I think it's a basic functionality. I'm not a Laravel expert but it's like that I've understand the implementation of Auth::

Comment: Oh in the filter you should verify Auth::check() is true and if he has good permissions (with [Auth::getUser](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html#502-510)) then you can switch in depends on cases.

Comment: I'm actually using filters to do that `Auth::check()`. The problem is the `Auth` system makes use of the `session` parameters and I want to personalize them depending of the section where the user is. I don't want to use the same session configuration parameters for my `public` and `admin` sections.

Comment: If you really want to detect a new environment you may use a closure to override the default function. In this function you could access to all super-global variables, including SESSION, and then you could implement your owns rules. I've edited my answer in this direction.